# Accessing JSP variable from javascript [Angular JS]

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp, session-variables

I am working with angular JS and JSP. i need to retrieve the session attribute variable from the JSP to my controller. My code is below

**JSP**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl as vm" style="height:100%">
        <md-content layout="row" style="height:100%">
            <div class="widget">
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/root/script/script.js"></script>
  <%
  String policy = session.getAttribute("POLICY_CHANGE");
  %> 
 </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   // i want to get the JSP variable here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set session value to hidden input.

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
     <input type="hidden" id="sessionData" />
</div>
<script>
     var data = '<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("POLICY_CHANGE")%>';
     document.getElementById("sessionData").value = data;
</script>
```

and get value

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $document) {
   $scope.data = $document[0].getElementById("sessionData").value;
   console.log($scope.data); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output the variable using expression language as a data attribute, like this:

```
<div data-my-variable="${myVariable}" id="myDiv"></div>
```

And if you are using Jquery, you can use the attr function:

```
var output = $("#myDiv").attr("data-my-variable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (I've never tried this - just and idea... please post if it is working):

```
<script>
angular.module('jspVariablesService', [])
.value("valueName",${yourVariable});
</script>
```

in `<head></head>` or at the beginning of body and then import jspVariableService in

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["jspVariableService"]);
```

and use it in controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", "valueName" function($scope,valueName) {
  //use your value!
});
```