# Bind value of an input in controller- AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-directive

I am working with JSP and Angular JS. I have a JSP page with a hidden input field. a session attribute is set to its value as follows.

```
  String policy = (String)session.getAttribute("POLICY_CHANGE");

  <input type="hidden" value="<%=policy%>" name="policy" ng-model="$scope.policyChange" />
```

How can i bind the value of the input field to a variable *$scope.policy* in my controller.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.policyChange= ; // i want to bind the input field value here.
});
```

Comment: [your question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300219/accessing-jsp-variable-from-javascript-angular-js/42302283#42302283) is it not worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this setting `ng-model` directive for your `input`:

```
 <input type="hidden" value="<%=policy%>" name="ng2_session" ng-modal="vm.policyChange" ng-model="policy" ng-init="policy='<%=policy%>'" />
```

In the controller you have to use `watch` method.

**$watch helps to listen for $scope changes**

JS

```
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   console.log($scope.policy); // i want to bind the input field value here.
 });
```

Simple example:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.$watch('policy', function() {
      console.log($scope.policy);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="policy" ng-init="policy='Bob'"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: Usually, `watch` method it is very helpful when you want to run `some` code when the `$scope.variable` it is changed.